# Which architecture for a an Angular side menu?

Tags: angular, navigateurl, angular-routerlink

I'm trying to make a side menu for an Angular project. I retrieve data from firebase but I do not know if my architecture is correct.

I have make a component with the selector app-serie-list:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let serie of series; let i = index">
      <a routerLink="series/view/{{i}}">{{serie.title}}-{{i}}</a>
</li>
```

and I have integrated to the app.component.html like this :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <app-serie-list></app-serie-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this time I don't know if my app-serie-list component is at the right place. Must do I put it in the component which take place in the router-outlet ?

And when the app-serie-list component is displayed, it changes the url of my web browser but it not change the router-outled displayed.

Comment: It looks like you didn't add routes to your app.routes file, do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example that we could have a look into?

Comment: I don't have added routes to an app.routes file but I have a constant "appRoutes: Routes" where I have declared : { path: 'series/view/:id', component: SingleSerieComponent },. The datas come a database, so they are dynamic. I don't have any errors in my console but the ngOnInit method from my SerieListComponent is not called. I don't understand what you mean by a reproducible example.

Comment: the answer would be it depends what do you want to achieve if you want one side menu for every route it can be as you did there but if you want possibility to have different layout for different routes you may want to have some intermediate layout component where you add this app-serie-list in different places check this for example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layouting

Comment: I want a one side menu for every route. I will check your snippet for finding what it could go wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Xesenix say my architecture is good. My mistake is on the SingleSerieComponent, the component that is displayed by the routerlink.

I have subscribed to the code which is in the ngOnInit method. So my SingleSerieComponent look like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-serie',
  templateUrl: './single-serie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-serie.component.scss']
})
export class SingleSerieComponent implements OnInit {

  serie: Serie;
  series: Serie[];
  serieSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private serieService: SeriesService,
              private router: Router) { 

    route.params.subscribe(val => {
      this.serie = new Serie(''); // on definit par defaut : chaine vide, 0 et chaine vide
      const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      console.log("id :");
      console.log(id);
      this.serieService.getSingleSerie(+id).then(
        (serie: Serie) => {
          this.serie = serie;
        }
      );
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("SingleSerieComponent-ngOnInit");

    this.serie = new Serie(''); // on definit par defaut : chaine vide, 0 et chaine vide
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log("id :");
    console.log(id);
    this.serieService.getSingleSerie(+id).then(
      (serie: Serie) => {
        this.serie = serie;
      }
    );

  }

  onBack(){
    this.router.navigate(['/pops']);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("SingleSerieComponent-ngOnDestroy");
  }
}
```